# android - html to pdf with kotlin webview and PdfDocument()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview, pdfdocument

I have a **HTML** file and I'm trying convert it to its **PDF** version, using **WebView** and **PdfDocument**.

What I've tried to do:

1. Showing the **HTML** in layout - this works OK.

```
    private fun createDocument(uri: Uri) {
        val document = PdfDocument()
        val pageInfo = PageInfo.Builder(595, 842, 1).create()
        val page = document.startPage(pageInfo)
        val rect = Rect()
        rect.set(0, 0, 595, 842)

        val view = TextView(this)
        view.text = "ANY TEXT"

        // formatting output
        view.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
        val widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(rect.width(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        val heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(rect.height(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        view.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec)
        view.layout(0, 0, rect.width(), rect.height())
        view.draw(page.canvas)
        document.finishPage(page)
        try {
            contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "w")?.use {
                FileOutputStream(it.fileDescriptor).use {
                    document.writeTo(it);
                    document.close();
                }
            }
        } catch...
```

2. Then tried outputting **TextView** to **PDF** - this works OK as well.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_show)

val towebView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
towebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
   override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
       view?.loadUrl(url)
       return true
   }
}
towebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/protokol.html")
```

3. I've then tried combining point 1 & 2; however this gives me a blank **PDF**:

```
    private fun createDocument(uri: Uri) {
        val document = PdfDocument()
        val pageInfo = PageInfo.Builder(595, 842, 1).create()
        val page = document.startPage(pageInfo)
        val rect = Rect()
        rect.set(0, 0, 595, 842)

        val view = WebView(this)
        view.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
                view?.loadUrl(url)
                return true
            }
        }
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/protokol.html")

      //formatting output
...
```

The only change I have is the background colour.

Any ideas on what might be wrong with this code?

Comment: You could [use `createPrintDocumentAdapter()` on `WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView?hl=en#createPrintDocumentAdapter(java.lang.String)) and bypass most of this code.

Comment: Nice. That is truly much simpler.

Comment: You might want to answer your own question and show what you wound up with for an implementation. Regardless, I'm glad to hear that you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So following [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)'s instructions I got simpler way of achieving same result, which looks this way:

```
private var mWebView: WebView? = null

private fun createDocument() {
    val view = WebView(this)
    view.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
            view?.loadUrl(url)
            return true
        }
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
            createWebPrintJob(view)
            mWebView = null
        }
    }
    view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/protokol.html")
    mWebView = view
}

private fun createWebPrintJob(webView: WebView) {
    (this?.getSystemService(PRINT_SERVICE) as? PrintManager)?.let { printManager ->
        val jobName = "${getString(R.string.app_name)} Document"
        val printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(jobName)
        printManager.print(
            jobName,
            printAdapter,
            PrintAttributes.Builder().build()
        )
    }
}
```